# Раздельное написание "не" с наречием "кстати"

Tags: частица-не

Дождь совсем не кстати.

"Не кстати" пишется раздельно, потому что перед "не" стоит наречие "совсем"? Или потому что отсутствует глагол?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Слитное написание слова «некстати»](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/nekstati-ili-ne-kstati.html)

> С помощью приставки *не-* образуется слово-антоним «некстати», которое
>   имеет значение «невпопад», «неуместно», «не к месту».
>
> *Грипп, которым
>   я совсем некстати заболел, расстроил все планы мирового чемпионства*
>   (Алексей Шалыгин. Вехи творчества одного поэта).
>
> В таком контексте
>   содержится утверждение, и рассматриваемое слово можно заменить
>   синонимом «несвоевременно».
>
> ***Наречие «некстати» пишется слитно в
>   предложении, содержащем утверждение.***
>
> *В ушах свистело, левая нога
>   некстати выскочила из слишком длинного стремени, сзади грохотали
>   выстрелы, что-то тяжёлое стукало по правому бедру* (Борис Акунин.
>   Турецкий гамбит). *У него в душе произошло нечто странное: стало
>   страшно досадно, что говорит об этом перед какой-то девочкой,
>   раскрывая свою душу; холодное чувство гордости легло на губы,  а под
>   ним хотелось хоть раз, хотя бы и некстати, просто высказаться* (М. П.
>   Арцыбашев. Миллионы).

[Раздельное написание слова «не кстати»](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/nekstati-ili-ne-kstati.html)

> Отрицательная частица *не* пишется раздельно с наречием «кстати», если
>   в контексте имеются некоторые лексические и синтаксические условия.
>
> **Во-первых**, в качестве пояснительного слова в сообщении может быть отрицательное местоимение или наречие. *Ваше условие никому было не
>   кстати. Нисколько не кстати ваше резкое замечание.*
>
> **Во-вторых**, в контексте отрицание подчёркивают слова «далеко», «вовсе», «отнюдь». *Далеко не кстати оказалась мне ваша подсказка.
>   Вовсе не кстати вы это сказали. Сегодня отнюдь не кстати он оказался
>   здесь.*

---

О наречии *совсем*, правда, не с наречиями, а с прилагательными, рассказывает [Розенталь](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm):

> При наличии в качестве пояснительного слова наречия *совсем* возможно
>   как слитное, так и раздельное написание не с прилагательными, что
>   связано с двумя значениями, в которых употребляется указанное наречие:
>
> 1)       «совершенно, очень»;
>
> 2)       «отнюдь», «никоим образом»;
>
> ср.: *совсем ненужная встреча* (совершенно ненужная, лишняя) – *совсем не
>   случайная встреча* (отнюдь не случайная, на не падает логическое
>   ударение).
>
> В некоторых случаях возможны оба толкования и, как
>   следствие, оба написания, например: *совсем небольшие достижения*
>   (маленькие, скромные) – *совсем не большие достижения* (отнюдь не
>   большие). В этих случаях для решения вопроса о написании не нужен
>   более широкий контекст.
>
> Двоякое толкование допускает и наречие *вовсе*:
>
> 1)       «отнюдь»;
>
> 2)       «совсем, совершенно» – в разговорном стиле речи;
>
> ср.: Против ожидания он говорил сбивчиво, путался, приводил *вовсе* не
>   убедительные доводы. – Авторами этих работ являются менее популярные
>   или *вовсе* неизвестные ученые. Как и в случае с *совсем*,
>   окончательное решение зависит от характера текста.

---

[Грамота.ру:](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=296040)

> Вопрос № 296040
>
> Как правильно: "совсем не удобная дорога" или "совсем неудобная
>   дорога" ?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Возможны оба варианта, но с разными оттенками значения. В значении
>   'отнюдь не удобная, вовсе не удобная' – раздельно. В значении
>   'совершенно, очень неудобная' – слитно.

Розенталь и Грамота процитированы для того, чтобы рассеять заблуждение, что наречие "совсем" всегда и категорически диктует раздельное написание с последующей частью речи.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь-то скорее слитно. Ибо нет ни явного противопоставления типа ***"не кстати, а*** "(оно вообще едва ли ли возможно со словом "кстати"), ни отрицательного местоимения типа "нисколько", "никому", ни усилительного наречия "вовсе", "отнюдь" и проч.

Так что, если такая орфография выбрана сознательно, то раздельное написание тут скорее авторская вольность, чем обоснованное правило. Это не ошибка, но специфическое авторское видение, возможно для отображения логического ударения на "не кстати".

Насчет "совсем". Я в первый вариант своего ответа влепил его по недоразумению. Оно-то как раз не может быть аргументом в пользу раздельного написания. Аргументами могут служить наречия, которые без "не" не используются ("отнюдь не") или используются редко и/или в другом значении ("вовсе [не]"): сказать "вовсе кстати" или "отнюдь кстати" невозможно, то есть наречие требует отрицания, а не образует новое качество. В отношении "совсем" это не верно.  Я не знаю, о каком заблуждении говорит Galina Avanesova и при чем тут грамотная "Справка" (там вообще о другом речь), но в целом - таки да. "Совсем" - не то усиление, которое требует после себя отрицания.

Comment: Ведь усилительное наречие "Совсем" присутствует

Comment: ой, это я зарапортовался, "Совсем" присутвует, но оно в мой текст попало по недоразумению. Исправил.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, ответ здесь проще. Частица НЕ с наречиями пишется отдельно за исключением наречий на-0, для раздельного написания которых требуется противопоставление: не всегда, не сразу, не зря, но "не быстро, а медленно"